# click event called multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button on my page which I wanted to use to trigger an ajax called, but i noticed the click would send multiple calls.  I tried to remove it to just show an alert, I'm getting multiple alerts coming up for 1 click.

My js code is on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#backbtn').on('click', function (event) {
        alert("called");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

the button is on the page as

```
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="backbtn" value="Back button" />
```

Clicking the button I see the alert come up 3 times, not sure what i'm missing, why it's called that many times for a single click.

Comment: How is the inline script being generated? Is it possible it's being output multiple times?

Comment: I just pasted the code supplied by you and it seems to be working for me - only one alert appears. Are you sure your problem isn't somewhere else?

Comment: Any other script also in action?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan you were right, I was injecting some html code with ajax into a page, when that area changed i was injecting the on click code again.  I moved it out of that area and it's called just once now.